# Can I migrate a question from SuperUser to StackOverflow myself?

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/337007/when-exactly-does-a-windows-program-pause-running) on SU and it became obvious to me that it was a programming issue (of mine) and not a SuperUser issue.  I added some more info, along with comments for the people who had responded - in the hope that they would revisit it - but the post seems to have gone cold.  I want to migrate it to SO, because:

- the problem seems as if it's a programming issue, so SO would be more appropriate.
- moving it to SO would make it "new" again and hopefully get some more responses (where I come from, a good way to sell a house that has been on the market for a long time without success is to take it off the market for a couple of weeks, then relist it).

Can I do that myself, or should I just repost it (and would that be seen as cross-posting, and make people growl at me)?

Comment: Sort of feels more like a Programmers question

Comment: In case you don't know it, random meant [Programmers.SE], our site targeted towards conceptual questions on software development, rather than concrete code issues like Stack Overflow.

Comment: Didn't know about Programmers slhck. Thanks.  @random, I still think its a SO question - i.e. the answer is likely to be a fragment of source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot move your question yourself. The easiest way to move a question would be to flag the question for moderators, and mark it as "off topic", and suggest it be migrated to the appropriate site. You can additionally just leave a comment in the flag instead, if you feel the need to explain your mistake.

Cross posting only makes issues when migrating it later on, so do avoid that.